# How to inline a tag in text with flex layout?

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I simulate the `display: box` with `display: flex`? It's seems that the `box` is abandoned, but I need render the element inline.

The `flex` will override the layout with it's own rule `row` or `column`. So the tag in `flex` container won't be rendered inline.

EDIT:
What I do is writing an user script for a page. I don't want to modify the parent of my element inserted. Otherwise I have to fit every page that parent is `display: flex` by myself.

EDIT2:
I don't want to change the struct of `text nodes<a href></a>text nodes`

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
}

#box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  width: 100px;
}

#a {
  display: inline-flex;
}

#tag {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
`display: flex`
<p id="container">
  <span id="tag">[TAG]</span>&nbsp; Hello world and&nbsp;<a id="a" href="/">StackOverflow</a>! Show me the money
</p>

Expected: `display: -webkit-box`
<p id="box">
  <span id="tag">[TAG]</span>&nbsp; Hello world and&nbsp;<a id="a" href="/">StackOverflow</a>! Show me the money
</p>

`display: block` is fine. But it will failed when tag display as flex(`inline-flex` is fine)
<p id="container" style="display: block">
  <span id="tag">[TAG]</span>&nbsp; Hello world and&nbsp;<a id="a" href="/">StackOverflow</a>! Show me the money
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign a width to the message.

```css
#container {
display:flex;

}

#message {
  width:5rem;
}
```

```html
<p id="container">
  <span id="tag">[TAG]</span> <span id="message">Hello world and <a id="a" href="/">StackOverflow</a>! Show me the money</span>
</p>
```

Comment: The width is unknown. And I can't wrap the sibling text nodes, it will cause style issue. What I'm doing is writing a user script that insert a tag into text nodes. I've added this line to post just now, sry XD

Answer (score 0):

Add another flex-box and set `flex-direction: column;`.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
}

#flex-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#a {
  display: inline-flex;
}

#tag {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<p id="container">
  <span id="tag">[TAG]</span><span id="flex-column">&nbsp; Hello world and&nbsp;<a id="a" href="/">StackOverflow</a>! Show me the money</span>
</p>
```

Comment: I can't wrap the sibling text nodes, it will cause style issue. The style of text nodes in `p` may different from `span` in `p`. Maybe I can use `inherit` for styles. I'll try now

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with CSS grid:

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto; /* 2 columns */
  width: 100px;
}

#box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  width: 100px;
}

#a {
  display: inline-flex;
}

#tag {
  display: flex;
  grid-row: span 50; /* a big value to create many rows*/
}
```

```html
`display: grid`
<p id="container">
  <span id="tag">[TAG]</span>&nbsp; Hello world and&nbsp;<a id="a" href="/">StackOverflow</a>! Show me the money
</p>

Expected: `display: -webkit-box`
<p id="box">
  <span id="tag">[TAG]</span>&nbsp; Hello world and&nbsp;<a id="a" href="/">StackOverflow</a>! Show me the money
</p>
```